# How do I get these specific values in this multidimensional php array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This may be a dumb question, but how do I return the values "ESEAX", "EAIIX", etc. from a multidimensional array that displays the following after using "print_r"?

```
Array ( 
[ESEAX] => Array ( ) 
[EAIIX] => Array ( ) 
[EANAX] => Array ( ) 
[EATVX] => Array ( ) 
[EVBAX] => Array ( ) ) 
Array ( 
[ESEAX] => Array ( ) 
[EAIIX] => Array ( ) 
[EANAX] => Array ( ) 
[EATVX] => Array ( ) 
[EVBAX] => Array ( ) )
```

I tried using indexes in various places (ie: [0]), and nested for loops.

Comment: show some code please `I tried using indexes in various places (ie: [0]), and nested for loops.` does not really answer the above question.

Comment: I don't really have code since I started from scratch but those 2 answers below helped me a lot already.

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about the keys of each array you can use `array_keys`. I.e:

```
$arr = Array ( 
"ESEAX" => Array () 
"EAIIX" => Array () 
"EANAX" => Array () 
"EATVX" => Array () 
"EVBAX" => Array ()) 

$arr = array_keys($arr);
```

Will produce an array like:

```
Array (
"ESEAX",
"EAIIX",
"EANAX",
"EATVX",
"EVBAX"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `array_keys` function should do what you want.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php